# Simplifying Javascript when having similar functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, simplify, simplification

I've finally pieced together some code that works for my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933751/reflecting-changes-in-class-for-back-forward). However, it appears pretty long as I've created separate functions for when a page with a certain hash is refreshed and when that same page is accessed via clicking the tabs.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        var loc = window.location.href; // For when Hazel is refreshed
        if (/Hazel/.test(loc)) {
            $("#tab1,#tab2,#tab3,#tab4").removeClass("r p c").addClass("h");
            $("#tab2").removeClass("tail");
            $("#tab3, #tab4").addClass("tail");
        }
    });
    $(function () {
        var loc = window.location.href; // For when Red is refreshed
        if (/Red/.test(loc)) {
            $("#tab1,#tab2,#tab3,#tab4").removeClass("h p c").addClass("r");
            $("#tab3, #tab2").removeClass("tail");
            $("#tab4").addClass("tail");
        }
    });
    $(function () {
        var loc = window.location.href; // For when Pink is refreshed
        if (/Pink/.test(loc)) {
            $("#tab1,#tab2,#tab3,#tab4").removeClass("h r c").addClass("p");
            $("#tab3, #tab4").removeClass("tail");
            $("#tab2").addClass("tail");
        }
    });
});
$(function () {
    var loc = window.location.href; // For when Cyan is refreshed
    if (/Cyan/.test(loc)) {
        $("#tab1,#tab2,#tab3,#tab4").removeClass("h r p").addClass("c");
        $("#tab4").removeClass("tail");
        $("#tab3, #tab2").addClass("tail");
    }
});
$("#tab1").click(function () {
    $(window).bind("hashchange", function () {
        var loc = window.location.href; // For when Hazel tab is clicked
        if (/Hazel/.test(loc)) {
            $("#tab1,#tab2,#tab3,#tab4").removeClass("r p c").addClass("h");
            $("#tab2").removeClass("tail");
            $("#tab3, #tab4").addClass("tail");
        }
    });
});
$("#tab2").click(function () {
    $(window).bind("hashchange", function () {
        var loc = window.location.href; // For when Red tab is clicked
        if (/Red/.test(loc)) {
            $("#tab1,#tab2,#tab3,#tab4").removeClass("h p c").addClass("r");
            $("#tab3, #tab2").removeClass("tail");
            $("#tab4").addClass("tail");
        }
    });
});
$("#tab3").click(function () {
    $(window).bind("hashchange", function () {
        var loc = window.location.href; // For when Pink tab is clicked
        if (/Pink/.test(loc)) {
            $("#tab1,#tab2,#tab3,#tab4").removeClass("h r c").addClass("p");
            $("#tab3, #tab4").removeClass("tail");
            $("#tab2").addClass("tail");
        }
    });
});
$("#tab4").click(function () {
    $(window).bind("hashchange", function () {
        var loc = window.location.href; // For when Cyan tab is clicked
        if (/Cyan/.test(loc)) {
            $("#tab1,#tab2,#tab3,#tab4").removeClass("h r p").addClass("c");
            $("#tab4").removeClass("tail");
            $("#tab3, #tab2").addClass("tail");
        }
    });
});
});
```

Is it possible to simplify it? I've tried but in my attempts so far, the code just breaks.

Comment: Yes, it is. What have you tried, please show us that code?

Comment: Why have you wrapped the first three addOnDOMready-statements in another $(document).ready?

Comment: this rather belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ than SO.

Comment: Is it possible that none of the four colors is refreshed? Or will there always be one the the four regexps within the URL? I'm thinking about an if-elseif-elseif-else.

Comment: @Bergi: I'll see if I can replicate them as I've already reverted my save file to the above code as it works for me so far; but as per Christoph's suggestion, I think I'll have to ask this question to Code Review instead.

Comment: @sp00m: This is actually a tabbed menu, so one of the regexps must always be within the URL.

Comment: @Christoph: Thank you very much for directing me to that site. I suppose it's the better forum for my question as I answered 'yes' to all the on-topic questions on that site :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're using some kind of a JS routing library.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tabInfo = {
            Hazel: {nonTail:'#tab2',tail:'#tab3, #tab4'},
            Red: {nonTail:'#tab3,#tab2',tail:'#tab4'},
            Pink: {nonTail:'#tab3,#tab4',tail:'#tab2'},
            Cyan: {nonTail:'#tab4',tail:'#tab2,#tab3'}
    };
    function makeChanges() {
       var loc = window.location.href; 
       for(var tab in tabInfo){
           if(loc.indexOf(tab) !== -1){
             $("#tab1,#tab2,#tab3,#tab4").removeClass("h r p c").addClass(tab.toLowerCase().charAt(0));
             $(tabInfo[tab].nonTail).removeClass("tail");
             $(tabInfo[tab].tail).addClass("tail");
             break;
           }
        }
    }
    makeChanges();
    $(window).bind("hashchange", function () {
         makeChanges();
    });
});​
```

Comment: I'm actually really impressed by how succinct your approach is and it partly works. Addition and removal of the h,r,p & c classes is perfect, but addition and removal of the tail class does not work so far. I've gone through the code though and nothing seems amiss.

Comment: @Clarice Is there some kind of an error reported in the console that you can share? Maybe you could add some console.log debug statements inside the if block before break to see if the properties are properly set. Do let me know, so that I can help you further. N sorry for the delay in my response.

Comment: No problem with the delay so don't worry. I'm told that 'tabInfo.tab is undefined' when I click on the tabs.

Comment: @Clarice Can you create a jsfiddle of your code? It'll be easier to debug. I feel that you've either not completed the `tabInfo` definition by adding the configuration for colors other than `'Hazel'` & `'Red'`. Also does this happen for all the tabs? Can you  also provide the browser & version that you're testing this on?

Comment: Here's the jsfiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/8WaTQ/1/). I simplified the css for it, but as you can see, basically nothing happens with the tail class (which should be visible or not on hover) no matter which tab is clicked. I'm testing this on Chrome 19, Firefox 6, and IE 9.

Comment: @Clarice I've fixed it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8WaTQ/3/) & Also edited the answer here. Hope this works fine for you.

Comment: It works perfectly now. As you may have noticed, I'm a newbie with all this, so thank you so much not just for the answer but for your patience as well.

Comment: @Clarice :) Next time maybe you can provide a fiddle in the beginning itself, that way there is a better probability that you'll get faster results.

Comment: Will do. TBH, I wasn't really aware of jsfiddle before, haha. :D Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This is untested psuedo code because I wasn't sure how to test the location part.  I tried to take an object oriented approach to your problem, moving all of the tab configurations into objects.

```
var tabs = [{
    "id": "#tab1",
    "color": "hazel",
    "removeTabIds": "#tab1,#tab2,#tab3,#tab4",
    "removeClasses": "r p c",
    "addClasses": "h",
    "removeTailIds": "#tab2",
    "addTailIds": "#tab3 #tab4"
}, { //Other tab configs go here ...
}];

$(document).ready(function(){
    var loc = window.location.href;
    var tab = getTab(loc);
    changeClasses(tab);
});

function getTab(loc){
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        if (/tabs[i].color/.test(loc)) {
            return tab[i];
        }
    }
};

function changeClasses(tab){
    $(tab.removeTabIds).removeClass(tab.removeClasses).addClass(tab.addClasses);
    $(tab.removeTailIds).removeClass("tail");
    $(tab.addTailIds).addClass("tail");
};

function bindTab(tab){
    $(tab.id).click(function(){
        $(window).bind("hashchange", function(){
            var loc = window.location.href;
            var tab = getTab(loc);
            changeClasses(tab);
        });
    });
}
```